# Query that reports if emplyee worked hours on specific days listed in a second table

Tags: sql, report, ms-access-2007

I need Ideas on how to approach a query in access 2007. Its to figure bonus for working particular days.

I have two tables that are imported from different software.

One table is daily and lists:

- each employee ID
- their part/full-time/oncall code status
- hours worked each day:

Example

```
Date       | ID  | jobcode |  hours worked |   
8/01/2012  | 003 | Full    | 8             |  
8/01/2012  | 004 | Part    | 4             |  
8/02/2012  | 003 | Full    | 8             |  
8/02/2012  | 004 | part    | 5             |
```

The second table has

- a holiday beginning day
- a holiday end day
- total hours each type of employee must work those days or range of days

Example:

```
begin      |   End      |  Parttime  | Fulltime |   
8/01/2012  | 8/01/2012  |      4     |    8     |  
9/01/2012  | 9/02/2012  |      4     |    12    |  
10/01/2012 | 10/01/2012 |      4     |    8     |  
11/01/2012 | 11/01/2012 |      4     |    8     |
```

There are about 30 holidays in a year and if an employee works all the required hours they get a bonus after one year.

I need to create a query that tells me the holidays for which the employees did not meet their requiement and how much they were off by.

I've thought of doing it in vba where I am more comfortable with the language.  Is that the better route?

I thought a Join of the dates would also work but not sure how to handle holidays that span more than one date.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Your life is a lot easier if you get the second table in a format that's more consistent with the first table. If you can get them to make that change, all you need is a join. (Although you ought to consider avoiding reserved words, and using more descriptive column names.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Date] date, [ID] char(3), [jobcode] varchar(4), [hours_worked] int);

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Date], [ID], [jobcode], [hours_worked])
VALUES
    ('2012-08-01', 003, 'Full', 8),
    ('2012-08-01', 004, 'Part', 4),
    ('2012-08-02', 003, 'Full', 8),
    ('2012-08-02', 004, 'part', 5);

-- I added this one, a full timer who didn't work enough hours on 09-01.
insert into table1 values ('2012-09-01', '003', 'Full', 11);

CREATE TABLE Table2
    ([begin] date, [End] date, [jobcode] char(4), [hours_to_work] int);

INSERT INTO Table2
    ([begin], [End], [jobcode], [hours_to_work])
VALUES
    ('2012-08-01', '2012-08-01', 'Part', 4),
    ('2012-08-01', '2012-08-01', 'Full', 8),
    ('2012-09-01', '2012-09-02', 'Part', 4),
    ('2012-09-01', '2012-09-02', 'Full', 12),
    ('2012-10-01', '2012-10-01', 'Part', 4),
    ('2012-10-01', '2012-10-01', 'Full', 8),
    ('2012-11-01', '2012-11-01', 'Part', 4),
    ('2012-11-01', '2012-11-01', 'Full', 8);
```

Now you can just do a join to get the right rows.

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from Table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 
  on t1.[date] between t2.[begin] and t2.[end]
  and t1.jobcode = t2.jobcode
  and t1.hours_worked < t2.hours_to_work;
```

Comment: Nope, that won't work. Full timers might work 8 hours on 09-01, and 8 hours on 09-02. This query doesn't sum the hours for a given holiday. (And I don't have time to fix that now, hence the comment.)

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL (I try to avoid MS Access), something like this ought to do you:

```
select x.* ,
       expected = case x.job_code
                    when 'Full' then y.Fulltime
                    when 'Part' then y.Parttime
                  end ,
       delta    = x.actual
                - case x.job_code
                    when 'Full' then y.Fulltime
                    when 'Part' then y.Partime
                  end
from ( select emp_id        = t.id      ,
              job_code      = t.jobcode ,
              holiday_start = h.begin   ,
              holiday_end   = h.end     ,
              actual        = sum( t.hours_worked )
       from employee_time t
       join holiday       h on t.date between h.being and h.end
       group by t.id    ,
                h.begin ,
                h.end
     ) x
join holiday y on y.begin = x.holiday_start
              and y.end   = x.holiday_end
where (   x.actual
        - case x.job_code
            when 'Full' then y.Fulltime
            when 'Part' then y.Parttime
          end
      ) < 0
```

We first use a virtual table (the subquery in the `from` clause aliased as `x`. This virtual table computes the actual hours worked for each employee for each specific holiday, using `group by` to summarize the data.

We then join that back to the holiday table (aliased as `y`) to get the expected hours worked.

The delta is computed as actual - expected, as you might expect. Expected has to be computed several times with `case...when`.

The `where` clause excludes those workers with a non-negative delta.

Easy!

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is tested and works for me. Changed some of the field names to avoid reserved names. Also added holiday name to the second table.

```
SELECT Hours.EmpID, Hours.JobCode, Holidays.HolidayName, Sum(Hours.HoursWorked) AS TotalHours, Holidays.Fulltime AS Req, [TotalHours]-[fulltime] AS Balance
FROM Holidays, Hours
WHERE (((Hours.DateWorked) Between [begindate] And [enddate]) AND ((Hours.JobCode)='full'))
GROUP BY Hours.EmpID, Hours.JobCode, Holidays.HolidayName, Holidays.Fulltime

Union

SELECT Hours.EmpID, Hours.JobCode, Holidays.HolidayName, Sum(Hours.HoursWorked) AS TotalHours, Holidays.parttime AS Req, [TotalHours]-[parttime] AS Balance
FROM Holidays, Hours
WHERE (((Hours.DateWorked) Between [begindate] And [enddate]) AND ((Hours.JobCode)='part'))
GROUP BY Hours.EmpID, Hours.JobCode, Holidays.HolidayName, Holidays.parttime;
```

The output I get (I added hours in Sept also) is:

```
EmpID  JobCode  HolidayName   TotalHours  Req  Balance
3      Full     Happy August           8    8        0
3      Full     Labor Day             16   12        4
4      Part     Happy August           4    4        0
4      Part     Labor Day              9    4        5
```

Comment: The key here was to use a WHERE clause with the BETWEEN statement, instead using a join.

Comment: The between solved the problem of the ambigious join I was getting after I posted this.  I was trying to create join between the date they worked and the begin and end date of the holidays.  The between was what I needed.